# WSO2 - How to use Endpoint in Registry resource project

Tags: wso2

I'm using WSO2 Intergration 6.6.0 , my attention : I want multiple projects can use/reuse Endpoint in registry resource project , is it possible ?
I [created a registry resource project with 1 HTTP Endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Working+with+Registry+Artifacts) , [created a composite application archive including registry resource project](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS350/Packaging+Artifacts+Into+Deployable+Archives) and upload it to ESB server successfully.
But I don't know how to use/import this endpoint in a project.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint exists in a registry you can use it like

```
<call>
  <endpoint key="gov:/endpoints/endpoint.xml"/>
</call>
```

In this example I used endpoint stored in governance registry in `endpoints` directory named `endpoint.xml`.